# Excel Remove text after string for multiple possible strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With Excel, I need to find and remove some text from all cells in a column. Using the example below I need to remove all instances of DEV or BA in this column.

Example data in a column:
Dan Smith DEV
Bob Jones BA

This example work but not with multiple possible matches.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND({"DEV"},A1)-1)
```

How can this be done with multiple possible matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

You may try any one of these, as shown in the image below, edited since what **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir has mentioned does make sense.

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=REPLACE(A1,SUM(IFERROR(FIND({"DEV","BA"},A1),0)),255,"")
```

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LOOKUP(9^9,FIND({"BA","DEV"},A1),{"BA","DEV"}),"")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Beware `SEARCH()` is **not** case sensitive where `FIND()` is. What happens when the data is `Devon Smith BA`? I'd advise to make that small change just to prevent false positives. +

Comment: @JvdV Sir, agreed absolutely correct, I always use `SEARCH` function and that's my bad habit, I will take this note seriously moving forward! Thank you so much again!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya How is this formula choosing to get the data after instead of before?

Comment: @DreadPirateRoberts why what issue are you facing may i know, please because `FIND` Function is case sensitive as mentioned above by JvDv Sir, So it checks for the exact `DEV` or `BA` in the end

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry, I realize now I'm trying do something quite a bit different. I need to do the inverse of this. "grep all of the after the match". I posted a new thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439994/excel-remove-text-before-string-for-multiple-possible-strings

Comment: @DreadPirateRoberts could you share few more samples in your new query, with the expected output

Comment: Data
Dan Smith DEV001 
Bob Jones BA005 
Bob Jones2 BA 005 


Needed Result 
DEV001 
BA005 
BA 005

I updated the example in the other post.

Comment: @DreadPirateRoberts i have posted the solution, do check!