# Excel Remove text before string for multiple possible strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With Excel, I need to find and remove some text from all cells in a column. Using the example below I need get all instances of DEV* and BA* into another column.

Example data in a column:
**Data**
Dan Smith DEV001
Bob Jones BA005
Bob Jones2 BA 005

**Needed Result**
DEV001
BA005
BA 005

This example works partially but not with multiple possible matches.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2) - SEARCH("DEV", A2)))
```

How can this be done with multiple possible matches?

Comment: Is it just the last 'word' you want (i.e. everything after the last space)?

Comment: @Rory I need to search on DEV or BA and fetch it along with all of the text that follows. In some cases the data will have space too. (working with old data)

Comment: Will the person's name always be in exactly two parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({"DEV","BA"},A1),""))-1,"")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to consider for those using ms365 with access to [`TEXTBEFORE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textbefore-function-d099c28a-dba8-448e-ac6c-f086d0fa1b29):

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,TEXTBEFORE(A1,{"DEV","BA"}),"",1)
```

- `TEXTBEFORE()` - will look (case sensitive) for either 'DEV' or 'BA' and will return the substring *before* the 1st occurence of any of these two;
- `SUBSTITUTE()` - will replace (also case sensitive) this returned substring with nothing. And to make sure we won't substitute unwanted parts after the lookup value we only replace the 1st occurence.

Comment: Nice One Sir!!!

Comment: Sir I can't discriminate with any of those, I have only used those which you have shown in solutions sir, ! I shall follow what you share, because every single info i will find in your solutions. Last but not least I like Excel in every form :)

Comment: Sir, in the formula above do we need `[instance_num]` --> `1` for `SUBSTITUTE()` Function ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Yes, that is just to be sure we don't substitute trailing text by accident. It's not likely in OP's data, but I wanted to make it a more generalized answer. Imagine data like `ABC DEV ABC 123`. Without the 4th parameter initialized to '1' it would substitute the latter 'ABC ' too. Now, by definition `TEXTBEFORE()` will return exact string before 'DEV' and if we substitute it just once it will always work safely trimming the text to the left of 'DEV' only. It's also explained (with fewer words) in my answer.

Comment: Yes Sir, thank you very much, I just tested with this `Dan Smith DEV001 Dan Smith ` & used the formula as you stated it worked as expected but if i remove the `1` then it removes the trailing `Dan Smith ` as well but only if there is a space after the second one. Very nice, So basically `TEXTBEFORE()` is an advanced form of `FIND()` Function. So using `1` is perfect & correct. Thanks again for the share of knowledge!